# TensorFlow bidirectional CudnnGRU ambiguous final state format

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/cudnn_rnn/CudnnGRU#call) for `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnGRU` states that `call` returns `rnn_output, rnn_state`. RNN state is a tuple, where in non-LSTM cases like GRU, it has a single element-- a tensor of shape `[num_layers * num_dirs, batch_size, num_units]` (where `num_dirs` is 2 in this case, for a bidirectional GRU). However, the documentation does not specify the order of the outer shape.

Succinctly, given an n-layer bidirectional GRU, is this tensor `[final_state_fw_1, ..., final_state_fw_n, final_state_bw_1, ..., final_state_bw_n]`
OR
`[final_state_fw_1, final_state_bw_1, ..., final_state_fw_n, final_state_bw_n]` ?

Answer (score 1):

The format is the following:

```
[final_state_fw_1, final_state_bw_1, ..., final_state_fw_n, final_state_bw_n]
```

I verified this by writing code that tests both ops and compares the results. Unpacking the way I claim is correct produces floating point errors of order ~10^-15, and significant error the other way around.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/danielwatson6/a5b72b5c2c21745efc20c78077f3ae95) to reproduce and verify (requires a device with a CUDA-capable GPU).